# When should I use a QListWidget over a QListView?

Tags: qt

From what I understand, QListWidget is built on QListView, and implements a "traditional" list widget, without any model/view concept.

Is there any situation where QListWidget should be preferred over QListView, or is QListView always a better answer once the model/view concept is understood ?

Comment: `QListWidget` is good only for prototyping, because it has performance problems on lalge amount of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QListWidget` is easier to use, even once you understood how models work. It can be handy to use in dialogs where a strict MVC separation is not that much of a concern.

Answer (score 5):

`QListView` is harder to understand, but far more extensible. For example, by implementing methods on it like [`canFetchMore`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) and [`fetchMore`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) on the model, you can create lists that gather more data as you scroll.

`QListWidget` is a narrow implementation of a `QListView`. It's perfect for prototyping and any situation where you might add and subtract small amounts of data to/from the list.

If your app isn't dependent on the list as its main element, you can probably get away with a `QListWidget`. If your core functionality comes from the list, you're better off tailoring a `QListView` to your needs.